# Solr/RDBMS synchronization DataImportHandler

Tags: spring-boot, solr

I would like to periodically do a sync between Solr and our RDMS without having to use the Solr's DataImportHandlr.  The reason being I would like to use Spring Boot's Cloud Config Server to manage the rdbms configuration,  so configuring Solr with the connection config would break that model.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: So how are you importing data today? Have you tried something like `cron`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can still use whatever you want to keep your configs, and use DataImportHandler.

The trick is to use [request params](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Accessing_request_parameters) to pass your username, pwd, host etc, so nothing is hardcoded, then, when you are going to trigger the DIH call, you read the good config values and pass them to DIH.

For instance I use it like this to externalize some of my values:

```
   <dataSource driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${dataimporter.request.DBHOST}:1521:${dataimporter.request.DBNAME}" user="${dataimporter.request.DBUSERNAME}" password="${dataimporter.request.DBPASSWORD}"/>
```